# How to update templates automatically in Django?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

Consider I am having a basic model like this:

```py
class Text(models.Model):
    msg = models.TextField()
```

I'm rendering a template like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Messages<h2><br>
        {% for message in messages %}
            <a> {{forloop.counter}} - {{message}} <br>
        {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

With a corresponding views:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Text

def home(request):
    context = {
        "messages": Text.objects.all(),
    }
    return render(request, 'app/home.html', context)
```

Assuming i am creating new objects of `Text` through admin page. If I save an object, I want to render it without refreshing the page. I don't have good knowledge on Javascript/jQuery/AJAX, but I'm aware that it is possible to acheive with the help of this. Can anyone guide me through on how to render the contents without refreshing the page?

Comment: Why has someone voted to close this as "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more" ? The OP is not asking for anything of this AFAICT ?

Comment: I'm afraid this is a bit too broad of a question - there are many ways to do this, from plain old (and rather crude) ajax polling to more modern (and much more involved) technos like websockets (cf django-channel for this). Now how to use jQuery to do ajax calls and update a part of your DOM is documented, how to set up polling is just a matter of using js `setInterval()`, and you alreadt how to return a response in Django (nb: you'll probably want a distinct view for the ajx requests returning the minimal needed html fragment to avoid wasting cpu cycles and ram).

Answer (score 0):

In such situation, **polling** is first option that comes to my mind. What you do is make a view which returns `JsonResponse`. Hope you know how to return queryset object by JsonResponse view

In straight forward way, allow view to return `Text.objects.all()`, before that you need to make queryset object serializable.
In optimize way, you could check if model(Table) entries are really modified, if yes then send modified entries only, or all entries for simplicity.

suppose you have this structure in html

```html
<div>
        <h1>Messages<h2><br>
        <div id = "msg-block">
            <a></a>
        </div>
</div>
```

on of ajax point of view, do this

```js
function update_messages(data){
     // suppose msg-block, is id of div enclosing all links, header div is sepreate
     str = ""
     for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
         str += `<a> ${data[i]} </a>`
     }
    $("#msg-block").html(str)

}

setInterval(function() {
     $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<url-to-json-view>",           
                data : {csrfmiddlewaretoken:document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value},
                success: function(data)
                {
                    console.log("Success  : ", data)
                    // function to update the table
                    update_messages(data)
                },
                error: function(request, status, error)
                {
                    alert(request.responseText);
                }
            });  
}, time-interval-in-ms)
```

enclose this in script tag, in your webpage and in normarl case to fetch data through ajax call.